# How an unassigned string is stored in memory and how to reference it?

Tags: c, string, pointers, reference, char

In this example seems that both strings "jesus" are equals(same memory location).

```
printf("%p\n","jesus");
printf("%p\n","jesus");
```

Also note that:

```
printf("%p\n",&"jesus");
printf("%p\n","jesus");
```

prints the same, but:

```
char* ptrToString = "jesus";
char* ptrToString = &"jesus"; //ERROR
```

So i wanna know how an unassigned string is stored in memory and how to point it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, why are `"jesus"` and `&"jesus"` the same: `"jesus"` is an array of type `const char[6]`, and it decays to a pointer to the first element. Taking the address of the array gives you a *pointer to an array*, whose type is `const char (*)[6]`. However, the pointer to the array is numerically the same as the pointer to its first element (only the *types* differ).

This also explains why you have an error in the last line - type *type* is wrong. You need:

```
 const char (*pj)[6] = &"jesus";
```

Finally, the question is whether repeated string literals have the same address or not. This is entirely up to the compiler. If it were very naive, it could store a separate copy for each occurrence of a string literal in the source code. If it is slightly cleverer, it'll only store one unique copy for each string literal. String literals are of course stored in memory somewhere, typically in a read-only data segment of the program image. Think of them as statically initialized global variables.

One more thing: Your original code is actually **undefined behaviour**, since `%p` expects a `void *` argument, and not a `const char *` or a `const char (*)[6]`. So the correct code is:

```
printf("%p\n%p\n", (void const *)"jesus", (void const *)&"jesus");
```

Comment: That was a brainwash, thank you, also, do you know a book or where can i find those particular details that some books do not offer.

Comment: We have a list of book recommendations in the FAQ. If you just have a simple question, you can also try our chat room.

Comment: "If it is slightly cleverer, it'll only store one unique copy for each string literal" - there's probably a range here, where a somewhat clever implementation stores one copy per TU, but a cleverer implementation merges these in the static linker (or even the dynamic linker so that you truly have only one copy of each literal per program, but at a guess that's more trouble that it's worth). IIRC implementations are also permitted to fold suffixes, such that sometimes `"sus" == "jesus" + 2`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Uniquifying strings at link time should be easy enough, but indeed, it's entirely up to how much the compiler is willing to do...

Comment: @KerrekSB : i've tried the  `const char (*pj)[6] = &"jesus";` but that gives the warning:  "initialisation from incompatible pointer type". Im using GNU GCC Compiler. its supposed that `array == &array == &array[0]` right?

Comment: @nEAnnam: Sorry, I was talking about C++ I suppose. In C, the type is just `char (*)[6]`.

Answer (score 1):

C is a carefully specified language and we can make many observations about your examples that may answer some questions.

1. Character literals are stored in memory as initialized data. They have type `array of char`.
2. They are not necessarily *strings* because `nul` bytes can be embedded with `\0`.
3. It is not required that identical character string literals be unique, but it's undefined what happens if a program tries to modify one. This effectively allows them to be distinct or "interned" as the implementation sees fit.
4. In order to make that last line work, you need:

   `char (*ptrToString)[] = &"jesus"; // now not an ERROR`

Comment: Are you sure your (4) is correct? GCC says "warning: initialisation from incompatible pointer type".